# TSQL dinâmico para multiplos retornos

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso fazer multiplas inserções que irão depender de um result existente em uma tabela como esta:

```
--CRIA TABELA #CONTATO
CREATE TABLE #CONTATO(
    NOME VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    TELEFONE VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
--INSERE 2 LINHAS NELA
INSERT INTO #CONTATO VALUES('JOAO','11-1111-1111');
INSERT INTO #CONTATO VALUES('MARIA','22-2222-2222');
```

Imaginem quem no exemplo acima eu precise que meu resultado seja algo do tipo:

```
PRINT 'MEU NOME É '@NOME+' E MEU TELEFONE É '+@TELEFONE;
```

Alguém poderia me mostrar como seria o SQL dinâmico que eu iria fazer, pois ja vi exemplos na internet que usam o `sp_executeSQL` mas não consegui entender como manipular quando houver esse caso... o retorno que eu gostaria de ter seria algo do tipo

```
--MEU NOME É JOAO E MEU TELEFONE É 11-1111-1111
--MEU NOME É MARIA E MEU TELEFONE É 22-2222-2222
```

Comment: Não tá muito claro o que você quer. A ideia é executar o que, exatamente?

Comment: Preciso que, para cada linha que existir dentro da tabela #contato, eu consiga através de um sp_executeSQL() pegar informações dessa linha, executar um comando; ai passa pra próxima e bla bla bla...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de usar parametros com o sp_executeSQL() realmente não é muito intuitiva, o melhor é mesmo ler a página da própria microsoft sobre o assunto:
[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Fica aqui a solução:

```
--CRIA TABELA #CONTATO
CREATE TABLE #CONTATO(
    NOME VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    TELEFONE VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
--INSERE 2 LINHAS NELA
INSERT INTO #CONTATO VALUES('JOAO','11-1111-1111');
INSERT INTO #CONTATO VALUES('MARIA','22-2222-2222');

DECLARE @Nome nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Telef nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @paramDefinition nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 'PRINT (''MEU NOME É '' + @pNome +  '' E MEU TELEFONE É '' + @pTelef);'
SET @paramDefinition = '@pNome nvarchar(10), @pTelef nvarchar(10)'

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT NOME,TELEFONE FROM #CONTATO
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR into @nome,@telef

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS= 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql  @sql, @paramDefinition
                        ,@pNome  = @Nome
                        ,@pTelef = @Telef

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @Nome,@Telef
END

CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
DROP TABLE #CONTATO
```

Comment: Valeu parceiro, não sabia que eu podia usar cursores e como aplicar o while dentro do SQL... Vou da uma pesquisada pra melhorar a solução que to criando, vivendo e aprendendo!

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
Insert Into Nome_Da_Tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3)
       Select Nome_Da_Tabela2.campo1, Nome_Da_Tabela2.campo2, Nome_Da_Tabela2.campo3
         From Nome_Da_Tabela2
```

Ou:

```
Select concat('Insert Into Nome_Da_Tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) values (',
               campo1, campo2, campo3,')')
  From Nome_Da_Tabela2
```

Obs: Creio que o concat esteja disponível a partir do SQL2012